# Slow building typescript project with webpack and ts-loader

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I have some strange situation with building my typescript project with webpack and ts-loader.

Command line: webpack --progress

```js
module.exports = { devtool: 'eval', entry: './src/app.ts', output: { filename: 'main.js', path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') }, module: { rules: [ { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' } ] }, resolve: { extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ] } };
```

some progress and message is hanging in console:

*93% sealing after asset optimization ts-loader*

and after a long time:

```
99% done plugins webpack-cli[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset main.js 4.18 MiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: main)
./src/app.ts 4.02 MiB [built] [code generated]
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  main.js (4.18 MiB)
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (4.18 MiB)
      main.js
WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 3 warnings in 1218503 ms
```

Does somebody know what can be wrong? How can I debug the problem?

Comment: Try to add [incremental] property to your tsconfig file and run webpack twice

Comment: the same time...

Comment: try in your ts-loader exclude folders without ts files